# Switching video drivers before boot

Tags: boot, graphics, amd

My laptop's AMD GPU is broken, so I've been using the basic display driver to run things in windows until now. I booted into elementary OS on the machine, but it automatically re-renabled the GPU and used the broken GPU as the display. How do I make elementary not use the GPU, and use the basic display driver instead?
Fwiw, running the GPU causes artifacts and screen freezes constantly.

Comment: First of all I think you should get it fixed. How did the GPU break

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about elementary and about hardware issues